# Create 3*3 matrix and ng-repeat that data but it's not working

Tags: angularjs

This is the response I am getting from server.

```
"data": [

    {

"id": 1,

"ticket": "[
        [\"5\",\"11\",\"24\",null,null,null,null,\"71\",\"88\"],
        [null,null,\"25\",null,\"42\",\"53\",\"61\",null,\"90\"],
        [\"7\",\"14\",null,\"32\",\"50\",null,\"65\",null,null]
       ]"
},
{
"id": 2,

"ticket": "[
        [\"1\",null,null,null,\"44\",null,\"61\",\"71\",\"82\"],
        [\"4\",\"19\",\"22\",null,null,null,\"68\",\"76\",null],
        [null,null,\"30\",\"34\",\"50\",\"58\",null,null,\"83\"]
       ]"
},
{
"id": 3,
"ticket": "[
        [\"6\",\"11\",null,\"31\",null,null,\"61\",\"76\",null],
        [null,null,\"22\",\"37\",\"42\",null,\"64\",null,\"86\"],
        [null,\"17\",null,null,\"47\",\"56\",null,\"77\",\"87\"]
       ]"
}
```

]
How to show matrix and repeat it in html

This is my code I have tried with.

I want to three matrix using repeat but right now data is showing in single row only

Please provide some solution for it

```js
for(var i=0;i<$scope.gameTickets.length;i++){
  $scope.ticket.push(JSON.parse($scope.gameTickets[i].ticket    );
  console.log("$scope.tickets",$scope.tickets);
}
```

```html
I tired this method
<div ng-repeat="ticket in tickets track by $index" ng-if="$index % 9 == 0" class="row">

<div class="column column-one column-offset-1">{{tickets[$index]}}</div>  
      <div class="column column-two column-offset-2">{{tickets[$index+1]}}</div>
      <div class="column column-three column-offset-3">{{tickets[$index+2]}}</div>
      <div class="column column-four column-offset-4">{{tickets[$index+3]}}</div>
      <div class="column column-five column-offset-5">{{tickets[$index+4]}}</div>
      <div class="column column-six column-offset-6">{{tickets[$index+5]}}</div>
      <div class="column column-seven column-offset-7">{{tickets[$index+6]}}</div>
      <div class="column column-eight column-offset-8">{{tickets[$index+7]}}</div>
      <div class="column column-nine column-offset-9">{{tickets[$index+8]}}</div>
</div>

//Another method I tried is this
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in tickets track by $index">
        <td ng-repeat="column in row track by $index">
            {{column}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a simple 3*3 matrix and rendered it in html using ng-repeat in `<tr> and <td>`
Hope this will help you

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.title = 'Welcome All';

  $scope.matrix = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
  ];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div>
    {{title}}
  </div>
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in matrix">
      <td ng-repeat="data in row">
        {{data}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```